# SchemaBuilder and start value of Id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, migration, orchardcms

I'm writing a module for Orchard CMS, and I need to set start value of Id as 15.
How can I do it via code?

In Migrations.cs:

```
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("NewRecord", table => table
        .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
```

and it creates column Id with primary key. What should I add to set the start value? thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so not in an answer: there's no direct way I know of, but maybe set the default value (.WithDefault()) to 15, then it will start from there?

Comment: As a last resort, if this isn't supported by Orchard, you could write custom DB call to issue the DDL yourself, to modify the seed value. Very hacky though, and not recommended unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all! The way to solve this problem - drop the primary key in table and alter column id? which was created automatically. I did it with SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSQL(string) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define this value from the data migration API.